# Add image at the bottom of navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-layout

My question is about android navigation drawer. Here is the screenshot of what I want to achieve.

[image]

I'm using default navigation drawer from `Android studio`. My question is very basic but I'm new in `Android studio`. Thanks in advance to all. This is activity_main layout. 
`

```
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">


<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@color/background"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>
```

`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">


    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="@color/background"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Rathor, what will happen if I have so many menu item so that it needs to scroll to reach the bottom of the NavigationView? If you know, please help me to solve this

Comment: @Omi then you can use custom NavigationView like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/51094894/7666442 BTW can you show some image what is your actual requirement

Comment: @Rathod here is the link of sample image. Please take a look. https://imgur.com/PuAZXBo. Iwant to give that 4 socaila image at the bottom of my navigation Drawer