# Navigation drawer with ListView instead menu

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

I made a custom Navigation drawer in the active with dynamic ListView instead of the menu. The Navigation drawer itself works fine, but all the View (buttons \ checkboxes, etc.) do not work on the OnClickListener. before that everything worked fine and in other activations everything works fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"><android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_fz_main" />

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include layout="@layout/nav_header_fz_main" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/nwBackButton"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="34dp"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_backspace" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
                android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout></android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In the active via Butter Knife initialization and with the Navigation drawer does not work anymore

in onCreate:

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
toolbar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this, drawer, toolbar,
        R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
        R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
toggle.syncState();
```

sorry for my english.
someone can help me?

Comment: Better to use **`RecyclerView`** check this answer  using `RecyclerView` https://stackoverflow.com/a/51094894/7666442

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem
just add to content layout

```
        content.bringToFront();
```