# Hide divider from under the icon in menu items android

Tags: android

I want to show the divider under the menu items excluding the icon in navigation view  in android. Can it be done native or I should user custom views.

Thank you

Comment: so finally you want show or hide the divider ?

Comment: show it under the whole item but not under the icon

Comment: @MohammadYounes than you need to create custom navigation view have look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51094894/7666442

Comment: you should try adding itemdecorator

Answer (score 1):

create xml like this ......

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group
        android:id="@+id/menu_top"
        android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:checked="true"
            android:id="@+id/drawer_item_timeline"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_timer_grey600_24dp"
            android:title="@string/drawer_timeline"/>
    </group>

    <group
        android:id="@+id/menu_bottom"
        android:checkableBehavior="none">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/drawer_item_settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp"
            android:title="@string/drawer_settings" >
        </item>
    </group>
</menu>
```

put every `item` in `group` tag.

If you don't need like this then go with custom one.

Answer (score 0):

Simple add DividerItemDecoration :

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
NavigationMenuView navMenuView = (NavigationMenuView) navigationView.getChildAt(0);
navMenuView.addItemDecoration(new 
DividerItemDecoration(MainActivity.this,DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
```

**Following is the Output..**

[image: Screenshot]