# Notification badge in navigation drawer

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to add a circular notification badge in navigation drawer here is my custom textview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
style="@style/Widget.Design.FloatingActionButton"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:gravity="center"
android:padding="2dp"
android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
android:textStyle="bold" />
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Required:**

[image]

**Note:**
If I set the textview height to wrap_content then textview will be circular but it will stick to the top.

[image]

Comment: keep it `wrap_content` but make `layout_gravity="center_vertical"`

Comment: Already tried, did not work.

Comment: try this if you want to use [custom navigation drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50252939/change-background-color-of-single-specific-menu-items-of-navigationview)

Comment: No, I just want to the change the counter not the whole item.

Comment: @SaddaHussain test case try this `android:layout_height="20dp"` in your `TextView`

Comment: Ok let me test.

Comment: No, it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a bug in Android. You can only achieve this by Trial and error.

Answer (score 2):

I just created a new View class to achieve this:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class DrawerBadge extends AppCompatTextView {

    private float strokeWidth;

    int strokeColor = Color.parseColor("#000000"); // black

    int solidColor = Color.parseColor("#FF0000"); // red

    // **** THIS IS THE FULL CONSTRUCTOR YOU HAVE TO CALL ****
    public DrawerBadge(Context context, NavigationView navigationView, int idItem, String value, String letterColor, String strokeColor, String solidColor) {
        super(context);
        MenuItemCompat.setActionView(navigationView
                .getMenu().findItem(idItem), this);
        DrawerBadge badge = (DrawerBadge) MenuItemCompat
                .getActionView(navigationView
                        .getMenu().findItem(idItem));
        badge.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        badge.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        badge.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(letterColor));
        badge.setText(value);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        badge.setLayoutParams(params);
        badge.setPadding(3,3,3,3);
        badge.setStrokeWidth(1);
        badge.setStrokeColor(strokeColor);
        badge.setSolidColor(solidColor);
        badge.requestLayout();
    }

    public DrawerBadge(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public DrawerBadge(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public DrawerBadge(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {

        Paint circlePaint = new Paint();
        circlePaint.setColor(solidColor);
        circlePaint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

        Paint strokePaint = new Paint();
        strokePaint.setColor(strokeColor);
        strokePaint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

        int  h = this.getHeight();
        int  w = this.getWidth();

        int diameter = ((h > w) ? h : w);
        int radius = diameter/2;

        this.setHeight(diameter);
        this.setWidth(diameter);

        canvas.drawCircle(diameter / 2 , diameter / 2, radius, strokePaint);

        canvas.drawCircle(diameter / 2, diameter / 2, radius-strokeWidth, circlePaint);

        super.draw(canvas);
    }

    public void setStrokeWidth(int dp)
    {
        float scale = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        strokeWidth = dp*scale;

    }

    public void setStrokeColor(String color)
    {
        strokeColor = Color.parseColor(color);
    }

    public void setSolidColor(String color)
    {
        solidColor = Color.parseColor(color);

    }
}
```

How to use? Just call the `DrawerBadge FULL CONSTRUCTOR` like this:

```
DrawerBadge badge = new DrawerBadge(this, findViewById(R.id.navigation_view), 
                  R.id.menu_item_id, 
                  String.valueOf(count > 99 ? "+" + 99 : count), 
                  "#FFFFFF","#FF0000","#FF0000");
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Using Relative layout for every row then use property in XML of textView center_vertical="true" and alignParentRight="true

Answer (score 0):

You have to fix text view size height & width in dp

Comment: It will stick to the top. Please try the solution before answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved in 3 steps using a ***custom*** drawable resource file.

First, create a **drawable resource file** with custom shape, `circle.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#37A667" />
    <size android:width="12dp" android:height="12dp" />
</shape>
```

Second, create your Custom *notification* drawer layout file, we will inflate this in our drawer activity, `notification_badge.xml`.

**These fields are important:**

- Surround TextView with `RelativeLayout`: RelativeLayout allows us to center TextView vertically
- Specify TextView `layout_width`
- Specify TextView `layout_height`
- Specify `background="@drawable/circle"`
- Set `gravity="true"`: Centers the TextView nicely within the background `@drawable/circle`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/counter"
        android:layout_width="16dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Finally, inflate the `notification_badge` view and `setText` to the TextView:

**In Kotlin:**

```
val customLayout = LayoutInflater.from(this@AdminMainActivity).inflate(R.layout.notification_badge, null) as RelativeLayout
(customLayout.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.counter)).text = "2"
drawerNavView.menu.findItem(R.id.nav_orders).actionView = customLayout
```

**In Java:**

```
RelativeLayout customLayout = (RelativeLayout) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.notification_badge, null);
TextView badge = (customLayout.findViewById(R.id.counter));
badge.setText("2");
navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_orders).setActionView(customLayout);
```

**Output:**

[image: Custom Notification badge example]