# How should I create that small triangle and background highlight color on EditText when focused?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I need help with this little triangle on `EditText`. I will probably do background highlight change with selector but I am not sure about the triangle.
And possibly when you will get to password `EditText` that triangle should slide down. I will appreciate any input. Thanks for you time.

This is `EditText` I am trying to achieve

[image]

Comment: Add a fixed triangle in the layout. Show hide(or move) the triangle on focus to the edit text.

Comment: as for color - create a statelist drawable with default and focused states, and set different background colors for those states.

Comment: To make the triangle slide you can make your own custom `SeekBar` and change the progress each time with `setProgress(int progress, boolean animate)`. VerticalSeekBar project: https://github.com/AndroSelva/Vertical-SeekBar-Android

Comment: @Rohit5k2 So i should put image of triangle in layout and handle it like that.
Thank you all for suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

> create layout like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rootView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgEmail"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/test" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtEmail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgPass"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:src="@drawable/test" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

> MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText edtEmail, edtPassword;

    ImageView imgPass,imgEmail;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        edtEmail = findViewById(R.id.edtEmail);
        edtPassword = findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);

        imgEmail = findViewById(R.id.imgEmail);
        imgPass = findViewById(R.id.imgPass);

        edtEmail.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus)
                    imgEmail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                else
                    imgEmail.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });

        edtPassword.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus)
                    imgPass.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                else
                    imgPass.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

> @drawable/test

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:pathData="M0,12l0,12 11.5,-5.7c6.3,-3.2 11.5,-6 11.5,-6.3 0,-0.3 -5.2,-3.1 -11.5,-6.3l-11.5,-5.7 0,12z"
        android:strokeColor="#00000000"
        android:fillColor="#000000"/>
</vector>
```

Comment: Thank you Nilesh. appreciated.

Comment: As a point of interest, Can you also tell, How should I also do the same in the Drawer, in which I have a Menu.?

Comment: I mean to say suppose if I have Menu, how should I do the same. In menu which is present in drawer have only title and icon.. Should we make a custom layout and inflate in menu to get the above look?

Comment: @UmangBurman yes you can do using custom navigation check my answer it will give you a hint https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50252939/change-background-color-of-single-specific-menu-items-of-navigationview

Comment: Ah, Thank you so much :)