# How to arrange menu item icon above text

Tags: android

How do I get to archive this in android. I want the icons to be above the text in vertical.

[image: How do I get to archive this]

This is my code

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:title="@string/todays_offer" />
        <item

            android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="@string/request" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
            android:title="@string/gas_shop" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
            android:title="@string/todays_sale" />
    </group>

    <item android:title="Communicate">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_share"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="@string/account_setting" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_send"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
                android:title="@string/share_app" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

so far I have I have archived to make it like this but I dint know how I can arrange the icons above the levels

[image]

Comment: create custom navigation using recyclerview https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50252939/change-background-color-of-single-specific-menu-items-of-navigationview

Answer (score 0):

Create custom layout in android xml custom_menu_layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingRight="10dp">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:text="your_text"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="9dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and use layout as

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_id"
    app:actionLayout="@layout/custom_menu_layout"
    app:showAsAction="always|withText" />
    </group>
</menu>
```