# Is there a way to change the background color of a single item from Navigation Drawer?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, background-color, menuitem

I have a navigation drawer menu as shown below:

```html
<?xml version"1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">
    <group android:id="@+id/grp1"       android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_my_company"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_item_company_layer"
            android:state_checked="false"
            android:visible="false"
            android:title="@string/nav_my_company"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_stock"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_item_stock_layer"
            android:state_checked="false"
            android:visible="false"
            android:title="@string/nav_stock"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_discount"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_item_discount_layer"
            android:state_checked="false"
            android:visible="false"
            android:title="@string/nav_discount"/>
    </group>
</menu>
```

I'm trying to make a single item have a different background color ( android:drawable = "@color/myRedColor") like this:

```html
 <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_stock"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_item_stock_layer"
            android:state_checked="false"
            android:visible="false"
            android:drawable = "@color/myRedColor"
            android:title="@string/nav_stock"/>
```

But I can not get it.

Any comments or suggestions are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Did you tried this? Might be this will help you...! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50252939/change-background-color-of-single-specific-menu-items-of-navigationview

Answer (score 0):

YES - you can create a `xml` file and include in your navigation tag :

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize">

        <include layout="@layout/a_main_navigation_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

and in `a_main_navigation_content.xml` you can create `textView` or anything u want with your custom attributes.

and you wont need your menu items anymore.

Comment: That's what I'm doing and that's not the problem. I want to change the background color of a single item, but all the items have the same color

Comment: nav_hardware = (MenuItem) menu_principal.findItem(R.id.nav_hardware);

Comment: man when you have 3 textView  in navMenu you can change the color of 3rd one or anyone you want by calling its ID or Createdobject. and if you using ExpandableListView you can change the color inside your OnChildClickListener code .

Comment: I can not find something that allows me to change the background color of the item.

https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DrMObGbW4AEWDQk.jpg

Comment: you still doing in your way , use any View but menu instead of your menu , like TextView sampleNavigationText = findViewById(R.id.yourTextView); the change like this : sampleNavigationText .setTextColor(Color.RED);

Comment: sampleNavigationText = null;

https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DrMSbshXQAAJuZZ.jpg:large

Comment: because it is not a TextView , !! have you read my answere at top of this comments?

Comment: you cant do that , create a new xml layout with forexample LinearLayout as parent , and create your textView inside of it , at the end include it in your NavigationView tag like my answere at top ^.

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience and help. I will try to make your suggestion and I will publish the results here

Comment: But your suggestion I have already made:

https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DrMa3rAW4AIjxaz.jpg

Answer (score 0):

In order to use benefits of Navigation Drawer and use custom bg, You need to write a custom navigation adapter. Then you can inflate whatever layout you want to. create a class that extends `RecyclerView.Adapter<NavigationAdapter.ViewHolder>`.

Comment: In a nutshell, it's not that simple.

Answer (score -1):

> If you want to use item tags and do this, as an alternative way you can tryBackgroundColorSpanand

s.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, s.length(), 0);