# How can I change spannable string background color with match parent

Tags: android, string, android-side-navigation

[image]I want to change background color of `textView` with match parent instead of text length in spannable string in android side navigation menu... How can I achieve this? Below is my code:

```
MenuItem quickAction = menu.findItem(R.id.quickAction);
SpannableString s = new SpannableString(quickAction.getTitle());

BackgroundColorSpan span = new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.YELLOW);
//for background
s.setSpan(span, 0, s.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
//for background
```

Comment: Check this [Change background color of single  menu items of navigationView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51094894/7666442)

Comment: how can i give match parent to title insted of length.. i have attached sample image